# Can strange paths cause a wrong structure of the file system?

Tags: java, file, path, filesystems, hierarchy

Consider the following example:

```
//both files are the same
final File path = new File("/home/alice/../bob/file.txt");
final File canonicalPath = new File("/home/bob/file.txt");

File parent = canonicalPath;
while((parent = parent.getParentFile()) != null) {
    System.out.println(parent.getName());
}
```

This would print:

```
bob
home
```

If I would use `path` instead of `canonicalPath`, would the output be the same or would it be:

```
bob
home
alice
home
```

This woule be very strange because it would suggest that `alice` is the parent of `home` which is not true.

Comment: Is your code compiling and is it really giving you bob and then home? Surprised!!!!!

Comment: You may want to fix your example. Even without the erroneous `final` `parent`, the loop is infinite.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh, yes thank you xD I'll fix it

Comment: Why are you using `File` instead of the new java.nio.file API?

Comment: With your current example, that is not the output I get for `path`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you want to compare `home/alice/../bob/file.txt` without a starting `/` instead of `/home/alice/../bob/file.txt`, otherwise you'd be comparing apples with oranges.

Actually it's more interesting to compare the difference using this code instead:

```
    File parent;

    parent = path;
    while((parent = parent.getParentFile()) != null) {
        System.out.println(parent);
    }

    parent = canonicalPath;
    while((parent = parent.getParentFile()) != null) {
        System.out.println(parent);
    }
```

The parents of "home/alice/../bob/file.txt":

- `"home/alice/../bob"`
- `"home/alice/.."`
- `"home/alice"`
- `"home"`
- `null`

In contrast, the parents of "home/bob/file.txt":

- `"home/bob"`
- `"home"`
- `null`

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't try it myself because I am currently on my mobile.

Answer (score 1):

The result would not be the same since those are two different filesystem paths.

But use `Path` instead:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("/home/bob/../alice/somefile");

final Path normalized  = path.normalize(); // /home/alice/somefile

path.toAbsolutePath(); // get an absolute path
path.toRealPath();     // same, but follows symlinks

// etc etc
```